Восстановление файлов
Можно ли восстановить файлы с диска, который был очищен при переустановки Windows, возможно ли их восстановить или же они уверенно полностью. Файлы по типу фоток и документов.

Как повезёт. Если не разбираетесь — лучше отдайте на восстановление в сервис

https://www.ccleaner.com/ru-ru/recuva

Попробуйте программы Acronis Disk Director 12.5 и R-Studio. Вторая работает очень действенно (по личному опыту)
